# Where I can store access and secret keys for callouts to AWS SQS service? Should I use Named Credentials or other means suit better for this case

Tags: callout, security, namedcredentials, amazon

[This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/aws-signature-version-4-in-apex) has an answer to how to send request to Amazon SQS service from Apex.

However, I am concerned that we have to expose access and secret keys in the code.
Is this possible to use `Named Credentials` or other means to store `accessKey` and `secretKey` in safe place?

When I try to use `Named Credentials` for request to Amazon SQS it just doesn't work when I replace endpoint from

```
req.setEndpoint( 'https://sqs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/' )
```

to

```
req.setEndpoint( 'callout:Test' )
```

Maybe I have configured invalid Authentication Provider - because I cannot create `Named Credentials` without it, and Amazon SQS is not in the list of authentication providers. I was trying to use `Open ID Connect` but I don't really need OAuth here, I just need secure place where I can store and retrieve access and secret keys.

Another problem would be how to access two keys from `Named credentials`. Even if calling `callout:Test` worked, how do I get two keys from it to pass to `createSigningKey('my-secret-key-here');` method?

I guess I could just use custom object with encrypted fields, but what are the best suggested options? Can we use something else?