# Salesforce to aws Dynamodb connection using Apex

Tags: apex, integration, aws, amazon-aws

I am trying to connect SFDC with aws Dynamodb from last few days using query string parameter but not able to generate signature correctly. 
I have followed steps mentioned in amazon document still I am getting below response:

> Reponse:
>   `<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>`

It seems either some of the parameters I am not using correctly or missing few items. I tried code/steps mentioned shared by one of the post mentioned by sfdcfox in [AWS Signature (version 4) in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/aws-signature-version-4-in-apex/89970?noredirect=1#answer-89970). With this I am successfully able to connect with S3 but while chaning parameters for dynamodb, I am facing issues.

Can someone help me on this?