# Trouble using HTTP callout action in Flows with AWS Signature Version 4

Tags: visual-workflow, namedcredentials, aws, amazon

I'm trying to make a very simple AWS API call out using an HTTP callout (POST request) in salesforce but I have been getting the following error.

```
{"__type":"InvalidSignatureException","message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}
```

I have set up a Named credential and external credential but it seems that the signature it generates for the request doesn't actually work.

My question is, has anyone ever successfully attempted this or it's a lost cause?

Comment: Does the endpoints contain a reserved character(Solved [KI](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAyuBAAS/aws-named-credentials-for-signature-v4-fails-if-endpoint-contains-a-reserved-character)). Also try using the [Python script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html) to make API call to same endpoint and see if it works

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Take a look at these examples with legacy Named Cred: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391441/aws-s3-implementing-crud-operations-with-named-credentials

Comment: @Swetha I think reserved characters has something to do with it but in this case the endpoint is clean. It's just 'https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'.