# Upload Image From Salesforce to AWS Server Using Integration

Tags: apex, integration, amazon-aws

```java
public class AWSImageUploader {
    public static void uploadImageToS3() {
        ContentDocumentLink attach = [SELECT id,ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title,ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.FileType,ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.versiondata FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId='0015j000014vKmzAAE'];
       system.debug('attach'+attach);
        String key = 'AKIAY7MBFGTAOCSDGIMM';
        String secret = '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';
        String bucketname = 'salesforceimagebucket';
        String host = 's3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com';
        //salesforceimagebucket.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
        String method = 'PUT';
        String filename = attach.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title;

        // Generate a formatted date string
        String formattedDateString = Datetime.now().formatGMT('yyyyMMdd\'T\'HHmmss\'Z\'');

        // Calculate the SHA-256 hash of the attachment body
        String attachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(attach.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.versiondata);
        system.debug('attachmentBody'+attachmentBody);
        // Create a canonical request
        String canonicalRequest = method + '\n' +
            '/' + bucketname + '/' + filename + '\n\n' +
            'content-type:' + attach.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.FileType + '\n' +
            'host:' + host + '\n' +
            'x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD' + '\n' +
            'x-amz-date:' + formattedDateString + '\n' +
            '\n' +
            'content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date' + '\n' +
            'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD';
        system.debug('canonicalRequest'+canonicalRequest);

        // Generate the string to sign
        String stringToSign = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n' +
            formattedDateString + '\n' +
            formattedDateString.substring(0, 8) + '/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request\n' +
            EncodingUtil.convertToHex(
                Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-256', Blob.valueOf(canonicalRequest))
            );
        system.debug('stringToSign'+stringToSign);

        // Generate the signing key
        Blob signingKey = Crypto.generateMac(
            'HMACSHA256',
            Blob.valueOf('AWS4' + secret),
            Blob.valueOf(formattedDateString.substring(0, 8) + '/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request')
        );

        // Sign the string to sign
        Blob signature = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA256', signingKey, Blob.valueOf(stringToSign));
        String signed = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(signature);

        // Construct the Authorization header
        String authHeader = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' + key + '/' + formattedDateString.substring(0, 8) + '/ap-south-1/s3/aws4_request, ' +
            'SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, ' +
            'Signature=' + signed;
        system.debug('authHeader'+authHeader);

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setEndpoint('https://' + host + '/' + bucketname + '/' + filename);
         // req.setEndpoint('callout:imageUploadAwsServer');
        req.setHeader('Host', host);
        req.setHeader('x-amz-content-sha256', 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD');
        req.setHeader('x-amz-date', formattedDateString);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', attach.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.FileType);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authHeader);
        req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
        //  req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read-write');
        req.setBody(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(attach.ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.versiondata));
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug('RESPONSE STATUS: ' + res.getStatus());
        System.debug('STATUS_CODE: ' + res.getStatusCode());
        System.debug('RESPONSE STRING: ' + String.valueOf(res.getBody()));
    }
}
```

Error is like

```xml
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391441/aws-s3-implementing-crud-operations-with-named-credentials