# AWS Signature expired (X is now earlier than Y (Z - 5 min.)

Tags: apex, integration, amazon-aws

I am currently working to integrate SF with AWS (Textract service to be precise) but I cannot get rid of this message: `{"__type":"InvalidSignatureException","message":"Signature expired: 20231128T131150Z is now earlier than 20231128T131450Z (20231128T131950Z - 5 min.)"}`
I've tried syncing my OS (Windows) clock but no success. Any ideas?
(As a side note, my TimeZone is GMT-03:00)
Another unrelated question: Could it be possible that secret keys containing special characters such as '/' or '+' contribute to generating wrong signatures?

This is what I got so far:

```
public with sharing class TextractDemo {
    String methodName;
    Url endpoint;
    Map<String, String> headers;
    Map<String, String> queryParams;

    Datetime requestTime;
    String requestTimeAsGmtString;

    List<String> signedHeaders;
    String payloadSha256;
    String key = 'key';
    String secret = 'secret';
    String service = 'textract';
    String region = 'us-east-1';

    public Textract2() {
        this.headers = new Map<String, String>();
        this.queryParams = new Map<String, String>{
            'Action' => 'AnalyzeDocument'
        };
        this.endpoint = new Url('https://textract.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/');
        this.signedHeaders = new List<String>();
    }

    private String createCanonicalQueryString() {
        List<String> results = new List<String>();
        List<String> keys = new List<String>(this.queryParams.keySet());
        keys.sort();
        for (String key : keys) {
            results.add(key + '=' + this.queryParams.get(key));
        }
        return String.join(results, '&');
    }

    private String createCanonicalHeaders() {
        this.signedHeaders.addAll(this.headers.keySet());
        this.signedHeaders.sort();
        List<String> results = new List<String>();
        for (String key : this.signedHeaders) {
            results.add(key + ':' + this.headers.get(key));
        }
        return String.join(results, '\n') + '\n';
    }

    String createCanonicalRequest() {
        return String.join(
            new List<String>{
                this.methodName,
                this.endPoint.getPath(),
                this.createCanonicalQueryString(),
                this.createCanonicalHeaders(),
                String.join(this.signedHeaders, ';'),
                this.payloadSha256
            },
        '\n');
    }

    private String createStringToSign() {
        String result = createCanonicalRequest();
        return String.join(
            new List<String>{
                'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
                this.requestTimeAsGmtString,
                scope(),
                EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('sha256', Blob.valueof(result)))
            },
            '\n'
        );
    }

    private String scope() {
        return this.requestTime.format('YYYYMMdd', 'Z') + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request';
    }

    public void uploadFile(Blob contentBlob) {
        this.methodName = 'POST';
        this.payloadSha256 = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(Crypto.generateDigest('sha-256', contentBlob));

        this.requestTime = System.now();        
        this.requestTimeAsGmtString = requestTime.format('yyyyMMdd\'T\'HHMMss\'Z\'', 'Z');

        headers.put('content-type', 'application/x-amz-json-1.1');
        headers.put('x-amz-content-sha256', payloadSha256);
        //headers.put('date', this.requestTime.format('YYYYMMdd', 'Z'));
        headers.put('host', endpoint.getHost());
        headers.put('x-amz-target', 'Textract.AnalyzeDocument');
        headers.put('x-amz-date', this.requestTimeAsGmtString);
        headers.put('content-length', String.valueOf(contentBlob.size()));

        String stringToSign = createStringToSign();
        String signingKey = signV4(
            this.requestTime,
            region,
            service,
            stringToSign,
            secret
        );

        String endpointFull = this.endPoint.toExternalForm();
        endpointFull += '?'+ createCanonicalQueryString();
            
        try {

            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setBodyAsBlob(contentBlob);
            request.setMethod(methodName);
            request.setEndpoint(endpointFull);

            for (String signHeader: signedHeaders) {
                request.setHeader(signHeader, headers.get(signHeader));
            }
            request.setHeader('Authorization', String.format(
                '{0} Credential={1},SignedHeaders={2},Signature={3}',
                new List<String>{
                    'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
                    String.join(new List<String>{this.key, this.scope()}, '/'),
                    String.join(this.signedHeaders, ';'),
                    signingKey
                })
            );

            HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static String signV4(DateTime theDatetime, String region, String service, String stringToSign, String secretKey) {
        Blob dateKey = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(theDatetime.format('YYYYMMdd', 'Z')), Blob.valueOf('AWS4' + secretKey));
        System.debug('dateKey: ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(dateKey));

        Blob dateRegionKey = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(region), dateKey);
        System.debug('dateRegionKey : ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(dateRegionKey));

        Blob dateRegionServiceKey = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf(service), dateRegionKey);
        System.debug('dateRegionServiceKey: ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(dateRegionServiceKey));

        Blob signature = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf('aws4_request'), dateRegionServiceKey);
        System.debug('final: ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(signature).toLowerCase());
    
        return EncodingUtil.convertToHex(signature);
    }}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Your call to `DateTime.format(...)` isn't going to give you a GMT timestamp, see [DateTime docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_3). AWS Sig V4 is available out of the box via Named Credential - here's an [example with S3](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391441/aws-s3-implementing-crud-operations-with-named-credentials)

Comment: Yes. I'm aware of the Name Credentials, but this time I decided to go custom. I also tried with formatGmt and the result is pretty much the same although the difference in time varies (with GMT it is more than 30min)