# Get Presigned URL using named credentials

Tags: callout, httprequest, namedcredentials, aws, calloutexception

I successfully obtained the pre-signed URL to upload large file to aws s3 bucket using the method described in the article https://mtr-design.com/news/how-to-create-a-presigned-url-for-aws-s3-using-apex. But, the drawback of this approach is that it requires sending access key and secret key, which I aim to avoid for security reasons. Therefore, I'm attempting to get the pre-signed URL using named credentials to enhance security. Below is the code snippet I'm using. I've hardcoded everything to test the functionality.

```
String bucketName = 'aws-sdbx-sftestdata';
String fileName = 'filename.pdf';
String location = bucketName + '/' + fileName;
String methodType = 'PUT';
Integer expires = 3600;
Integer contentLength = 1000; 

Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:AWS_Connection/' + location);
req.setMethod(methodType);
req.setHeader('X-Amz-Expires', String.valueOf(expires));
req.setHeader('X-Amz-SignedHeaders', 'host');
req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueof(contentLength));

HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

However, when I execute it in the anonymous window, I encounter a System.CalloutException: Read timed out error. Even though I increased the timeout value, I still got the error. Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 - implementing CRUD operations with Named Credentials](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391441/aws-s3-implementing-crud-operations-with-named-credentials)

Comment: @identigral In that question, they did not mention obtaining a presigned URL using named credentials. I'd be happy to help you resolve this.