# External Credential for Amazon - SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: apex, namedcredentials, amazon-s3, externalcredentials, amazon-aws

I'm trying to updload files from SF to S3 using an External Credential.

My user has permissions to access the External Credential, User Credentials, and the Named Prinicipal.

I have confirmed that the Accesskey & Secret Id are correct, output the endpoint to verify the url, tried using mybucket.s3.amazonaws and s3.amazonaws/mybucket formats, etc.

When the url is incorrect I get an error about bucket not available, but otherwise I keep running into the following:

```
SignatureDoesNotMatch
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
Check your key and signing method.</Message>.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can try to get through this?

In addition to the Salesforce documentation on External credentials, I used this as a guide:
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/integrate-salesforce-amazon-s3-within-15-min-sfdcpanther/

Here's a minimum version of the code I'm using to make the callout:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('PUT');
req.setEndpoint('callout:s3_external_credential/' + fileName);
req.setBodyAsBlob(contentVersion.VersionData);
try {   
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    if(res.getStatusCode() == 200 || res.getStatusCode() == 201){
       ....
    } else{
        String message = 'Error uploading file to s3. File url: ' + fileUrl + '\nError: ' 
            + res.getStatus();
        System.debug(message);
        ...
    }
} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    ....
}
```

And the relevant log lines (I replaced my actual bucket name with the text mybucket-name):

```
10:10:10.486 (10140967505)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|[92]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=callout:S3_Access/Lead/00QR000000OR1P2MAL/admission_reconciliation_error.csv, Method=PUT]
10:10:11.913 (10913455454)|NAMED_CREDENTIAL_REQUEST|NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=0XAR00000008fcP, Named Credential Name=S3_Access, Endpoint=https://mybucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/Lead/00QR000000OR1P2MAL/admission_reconciliation_error.csv, Method=PUT, External Credential Type=EXTERNAL, HTTP Header Authorization=Set, Content-Type=null, Request Size bytes=1094991, Retry on 401=True]
10:10:11.914 (10914609907)|NAMED_CREDENTIAL_RESPONSE_DETAIL|<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
```

I also tried a basic list command:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setMethod('GET');
request.setEndpoint('callout:' + GlobalConstants.S3_NAMED_CREDENTIAL_NAME);
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(request);
Assert.areEqual(200,res.getStatusCode());
System.debug(res);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

And received an identical error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 - implementing CRUD operations with Named Credentials](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/391441/aws-s3-implementing-crud-operations-with-named-credentials)

Comment: @identigral thank you - I had looked at that earlier, and it didn't.

Comment: Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: @identigral any suggestions? The same credentials work from the aws cli.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error last year and it happens when you do not properly encode your object or bucket in your request: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html

For example: If you were to create a canonical URI and encode the spaces in your URI as a `+` instead of `%20` you would get this error. However, since you replace all these chars with a `-` this cannot be the problem.

So I would guess that the configured bucket does contain a space or something else that's not properly working. You can also try passing a much simpler filename in case there's an error in the regex I didn't catch.

However, you would probably need to share more details about the data you're putting in that causes this error so people can properly help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, but my filename doesn't include and special characters.